# Employer revised my salary without discussing with me. Is it even legal?

Tags: software-industry, management, india, software

I got a new job 2 months ago and the pay was good given that I will be getting married and need to take of my mother's medical bills. I have a different salary during my probation and a higher one after it ends.

My new company had a probation for 2 months. In the first month, I wanted 2 days off to go home and I asked my manager if I could talk to him personally, and during the conversation he said, "I expect more from you as a senior developer and I'm not happy with your deliverable".

I told him that I may be upset about my mother's health but I have been putting long hours and finishing my work(My work exceeded the due date by 1-2 days.) He told me we can keep you here if we revise your salary. I told him salary revision is fine. (I was offered a 50% hike. Even if it reduced I would be content).

Later a month goes by and I ask him again if I am doing well. He said "I have not evaluated you but the tasks given to you were easy ones and I will revise the salary before probation ends". I said salary revision is fine and he asks for my previous company's pay slip.

He made my current salary same as my previous company's salary and credited the amount on first of this month, without sending me a new offer or me signing any document or any information even on Slack or E Mail.

I am also going to get married and I really liked this job, did not think of switching jobs again. I spoke to my manager about this and he is only willing to increase a little from my previous company.

He knows I need money and job hunting will take time. I feel he has royally screwed me over.

I thought there would be a negotiation at least. I never thought they would decide a number and I should just be okay with it. How do I deal with it now? What do I do?

My contract does not mention that they can revise my salary anytime without my consent. It only says I need to give a 2 months notice and that they also will give a 2 months notice.

Comment: Why did you give him your payslip from your old company?

Comment: Also if down voting, please explain so. I'll make the changes.

Comment: @JohnHC My contract does not mention that they can revise my salary anytime without my consent. It only says I need to give a 2 months notice (Written) and that they will  also give a 2 months notice.

Comment: General rule of thumb: any question of "is it legal" should probably go to the Legal SE.

Comment: @Kevin I understand, thanks. I also wanted to know if this happens in workplaces and how to tackle this. I probably will try to avoid this being a legal issue or going to courts.

Comment: "job hunting will take time" with that acknowledgement perhaps it's better to start earlier than later

Comment: This was done to a colleague... He handed his notice in so his last day was about 2 weeks before the delivery of the large project... Manager was understood very quickly... Amazing how things got sorted for him.

Comment: @Wilson It appears to be a common demand by Indian employers.  And if the questions where it's mentioned are representative the knowledge is abused as badly as you would expect.

Comment: Is the two months notice in effect from hiring, or after the probation period? Did he reduce your current salary, or the post-probation salary?

Comment: _"He made my current salary same as my previous company's salary"_ - that's why you should **never** say what your previous salary was.

Comment: Why keep you if you're not being productive? this is just a scummy cost reduction as it happens often, this is a big big red flag and this company is highly unethical you kept your  job that's a good thing but start sending resumes asap and get out

Answer (score 25):

He literally said to you, “we can keep you here if we revise your salary,” and you agreed. Then he checked this with you again, and asked for evidence of what you were paid last time, and then paid you that. It sounds to me as if there was ample communication and feedback. Your contract was modified for cause, based on your performance during the probation period. That’s better than firing you, right?

Comment: I am not sure if it was based on performance. I was performing well and exceeding the due date by a day or two was common in this workplace. There was extensive testing done and some changes had to be made which where not there in the initial specifications. 

But I wasn't even given a new offer with the revised salary or communicated that it has been indeed revised. I got a 50% increment. Even if 20% increment would be given I would have agreed but I quit my previous company only for the salary and I was explicit enough. Going back to the previous salary makes no sense.

Comment: The problem is that you told him a revision would be fine, without saying anything about numbers : (

Comment: You did say it was OK, but it's not necessarily too late. If you are unhappy with your new salary, go **immediately** to your boss and say "I know I agreed to a salary revision but that's too low. Can we agree on something in between?"

Comment: Yes @DJClayworth I went today and spoke to him and he said he can do a 10-12% raise. He started bringing old things up saying, "you were never here for money but to learn new things".

I am also upset as how can the revised salary even be credited without my knowledge, or a new offer letter or some type of communication, at least through E Mail.

Comment: @Joshua Read what you wrote in the question. "He told me we can keep you here if we revise your salary. I told him salary revision is fine." If you start acting all "I never agreed to this" when you did agree you will only make things worse for yourself. And next time remember not to say "salary revision is fine" but say "it depends on how much".

Comment: @DJClayworth I thought it would be a negotiation at least. I never thought they would decide a number and I should just be okay with it. How do I deal with it now? What do I do?

Comment: You do what you've done. You just negotiated. They offered you 10-12%. If you think you need more then ask for more, just like you would with any negotiation. But be aware that if you don't reach an agreement then you will probably be fired.

Comment: @Joshua - To continue the train of thought others have said, you have now negotiated a 10-12% pay increase, only you can decide if that is a large enough pay increase.  It is worth pointing out, your manager literally told you, they were not happy with your performance.  While I don't agree your manager should have changed your pay in the way you describe, I also know that there are two sides to every story.  *You should take heed to what others are saying, during a 2 month probation time, you were told your manager wasn't happy with your performance and your pay was adjusted.&

Comment: @Joshua - It is worth pointing out that your manager communicated with you in person.  Based on that communication they took action, it is clear by their actions, they didn't see the need to communicate in informal methods like a followup email.

Answer (score 9):

Ignoring the conversations you had with your manager, you must have a signed contract which has your salary on it when you started the employment?

If your contract has now been changed (even if you verbally suggested you would be ok with this), where is the new signed contract? Have you been provided with any documentation of this change? If not I would go immediately to HR and ask for a copy of your contract. This will either be the original one which they have broke by not paying you the agreed amount, or a new one which you haven't agreed to in writing (it appears). Any verbal agreement wouldn't hold up to scrutiny in my opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure about India, but there are jurisdictions where contracts do not need to be written. A verbal contract is as binding and valid as a written one in Germany, for example. IANAL and I have no clue about Indian contract law, but just saying it needs to be in writing could bite the OP.

Comment: @Polygnome Still though, I'm not sure if "a salary revision is fine" is a tight enough verbal contract to change the salary without the other party agreeing to the new salary.

Comment: @JMac True. One would expect negotiations to follow and an agreement to be reached. But OP was asked for a payslip and handed it over. Without knowing exactly how that went, it could very well be that his employer understood this to be the negotiation. This whole thing is a question for a lawyer.

Comment: @Polygnome India has a similar stance on oral agreements, but if their law is anything like the German one (at a cursory glance: very similar), this answer is still solid advice. Some agreements *need* to be in writing still. Also at the very minimum, such a contract would have to be *specific*, i.e. you need to know the proposed new salary to consent to it. The details of oral agreements are also nigh impossible to prove in court. And last but not least, unclear phrasing is typically interpereted in favor of the weaker party. I agree 100% that they should get a lawyer, of course.